# Install Ubuntu 18.04 on the same disk with Windows already installed in uefi mode. How to do it correctly?

Tags: windows-10, ubuntu, multi-boot, uefi

In fact, I have always disliked installing two operating systems on the same disk because one boot loader can wipe the other. But this time I'm not dealing with my computer. Also, there is no way to install a second hard disk drive. And at the end of the day one system is already installed in uefi mode and the second system is also planned to be installed in uefi mode. That's why I thought there might be some method of installation that would not lose the ability to boot Windows and also not lose the ability to boot in Ubuntu after some Windows updat?